# trouble with constructing from initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I have a class which shall have many different constructor overloads, one of which is from an `initializer_list`. Unfortunately, this will be picked automatically when I use [list-initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) as in

```
class foo
{
  template<typename T>
  foo(T const&it);

  template<typename T>
  foo(std::initializer_list<T> list);
};

template<typename other>
foo bar(other const&it)
{
  return {it};
}
```

when the second constructor is called, not the first. This is correct but counter intuitive and hence dangerous. How can I prevent that? I would be happy with a solution where the second constructor specialises for the case that `list.size()==1`. For example

```
template<typename T>
foo::foo(std::initializer_list<T> list)
  : foo(list.begin(), list.size()) {}

template<typename T>              // private constructor
foo::foo(const T*p, size_t n)
{
  if(n==1)
    foo::foo(p[0]);               // this does not what I want
  else {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

where I try to explicitly call the first constructor from within another constructor. Is this possible? (the code compiles, but doesn't appear to call the intended constructor or in fact any constructor). The only way I could make this work was by using placement new:

```
template<typename T>              // private constructor
foo::foo(const T*p, size_t n)
{
  if(n==1)
    ::new(this) foo(p[0]);        // seems to work
  else {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

However, this is at least inelegant if not outright dangerous. Are there better solutions?
Note that trying to replicate the effort of the first constructor instead of calling it is not really a useful solution, as there will be many different first constructors for different type of arguments using SFINAE.

Comment: Unfortunately `size()` is not `constexpr`, So you can't use SFINAE based on `size()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Of course. Though in practice, an `initializer_list` is only ever constructed implicitly, so the size is known to the compiler and hence could be `constexpr`.

Comment: Seems you might in C++14 : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size

Comment: Can you explain why the `initializer_list` constructor being selected is a problem? Seems to me the end result should be the same whether your class is constructed from a single `T const&` argument, or an `initializer_list<T>` containing a single element.

Comment: The language has been designed specifically so that `return {it};` prefers the `initializer_list`. You are trying to go opposite to the intentions of the language. Can you tell us what real problem you are trying to solve? (Note that using `return it;` would pick the desired overload.)

Comment: I decided that the construction from `initializer_list<>` is not worth the trouble. I can always pass the contents of the list to the constructor in another form, should the need arise for generating an object from such a list.

Comment: Well, the *real problem* is to generate something like `boost::any` but allowing array-like data, i.e. holding the *data* of containers (== anything that has `begin()` and `end()`) rather than the container itself (if a second argument to the constructor indicates that this is desired). Initially, I also thought it useful to construct from an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @Praetorian That is what I wanted: same result for construction from `initializer_list` with single element or from a single element. However, I had trouble to implement this: *if* I have a constructor taking a `initializer_list` argument, then it will be called and cannot simply call the other constructor in the member-initialisation list (between `:` and `{ body of constructor }`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use variadic template instead of `initializer_list`.
Something like:

```
#include <type_traits>

// equivalent to std::is_same but for more type.
template <typename... Ts> struct are_same : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct are_same<T> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T, typename ...Ts> struct are_same<T, T, Ts...> : are_same<T, Ts...>  {};

class foo
{
    struct dummy_t {};
public:
    template <typename...Ts, typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Ts) > 1) && are_same<typename std::decay<Ts>::type...>::value>::type>
    foo(Ts&&... args);

    template<typename T>
    foo(T const&it);

};
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't answer the question. You didn't even try to. And **No**, I cannot use a variadic template instead, for I want to allow multi-valued initialiser lists as in `test={0,1,2,3};`